# Tracking Local Edits of Git Submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm starting this this really isn't possible with Git submodules after head scratching and searching but here it goes:

I've pulled the Ghost (node.js blog platform) repo rendered by a cloud provider.

It resides at C:/sites/blog/ and pushes to my cloud server

I've made a submodule of a theme I found on a github repo.  It resides at C:/sites/blog/content/themes/SubmoduleTheme

I've tried to figure out how to customize the theme while pushing from the blog's root directory to the cloud server.

It seems submodules require any commits to be pushed to a different repo than the "super" repo.  Is this the case--that localized changes to submodule can't be included in the main repo to the cloud, are there any ~relatively simple~ Git alternatives?

Comment: You can keep any history in any repo you want -- including carrying a submodule's history in the repo using the submodule, using the main repo as the submodule's upstream.  Is that what you want?

Comment: If by submodule's upstream you would mean that the main Ghost repo would have presidence over the theme's repo, then yes as long as it's feasible to merge updates from the theme repo from time to time.

Comment: The repo in the `.gitmodules` file is just a suggestion.  The one the local repo uses is in the local repo's config.  All of the metadata about a history is repo-local and _utterly_ arbitrary, configure it how you like -- the commit graphs areall that matters, and you can schlep them around among repos and label them however you like, arbitrarily, in every repo.  In your personal repos the organization only has to make sense to you personally.

Comment: So I would go about achieving my desired state by changing  C:/sites/blog/.blog/config submodule's URL to the same URL as the Ghost blog?  That might do it in theory... let's see if I break anything in the process...

Comment: If you'll get really concrete about the current setup in the question I can get more detailed with the help, but I'd think the experimentation you're talking about is far and away the best course. If you get stuck, ask it as a separate question and comment here to get my attention, yeah?

Comment: Sure thing, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems subtrees are the functionality I want and implemented.  The following does a good job of explaining how-to:

http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/